# Using array to show order of the same RadioButtonList items randomly

Tags: c#, asp.net

I use array to generate order of RadioButtonList items randomly but when I select one of radio buttons the selection well be released and generate an other order

I'm trying to get a question and adding options for it in the radio button list from a table in my database and I want to change the list order of the radio buttons for each user.

My codes:

```
RBList.ClearSelection();
    RBList.Items.Clear();
    string[] arr = new string[4]{
        ds.Tables["Quiz"].Rows[0][1].ToString(),
        ds.Tables["Quiz"].Rows[0][2].ToString(),
        ds.Tables["Quiz"].Rows[0][3].ToString(),
        ds.Tables["Quiz"].Rows[0][4].ToString()
    };
    System.Random rnd = new System.Random();
    arr = arr.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).ToArray();

    RBList.Items.Add(arr[0]);
    RBList.Items.Add(arr[1]);
    RBList.Items.Add(arr[2]);
    RBList.Items.Add(arr[3]);

    ques1.Text = (ds.Tables["Quiz"].Rows[0][0]).ToString();
    int p = Convert.ToInt32(q_no.Text);
    p += 0;
    q_no.Text = p.ToString();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you only need to check if the page is being rendered for the first time, then randomize the RadioButtonList items. Something like this,

```
private void Page_Load()
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        // your randomize code
    } else {
        // retrieve the selected item, but don't randomize the items again.
    }
}
```